# How can I check if the consumption incident rate stays constant over time through statistics tests?

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

We have the time interval when high-weight and low weight flies were eaten by a spider and then we have those who survived. [image]
How can I check if the consumption incident rate stays constant over time?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in the total data, then one way would be to do a one-way chi-square test against the assumption of a uniform distribution.

But I'd suggest instead doing a logistic regression with "survived" as the dependent variable and "time period" as the independent variable.  If desired, you could also add "weight" and possibly the interaction of weight and time as other independent variables.

Comment: Should I apply chi-square test on this table or should I transform the table?

Comment: If you are interested in the whole sample and are ignoring my advice to do logistic regression then you would do a one sample chi square test on 46,13,16,12 vs. a uniform distribution.  "Transform the table" doesn't really make sense.